# generic extension method on IQueryable<T>

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

I've written an extension method on IQueryable which returns the same type of IQueryable, just filtered a bit.
Let's say it's something like that:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Foo<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int? howmany = null)
{
    if (howmany.HasValue)
        return source.Take(howmany.Value);
    return source;
}
```

calling the above method is as simple as `someLinqResult.Foo(2)`

I need other method that will return instance of other **generic class, but with other base class** (not the same as source `T` above).
So, here's the code, let's assume this method is supposed to return a list of given type (other than the input type which IQueryable has!) but the same length [the actual problem is about transforming NHibernate query results, but it doesn't matter):

```
public static List<TTarget> Bar<TTarget,TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    return new List<TTarget>(source.Count());
}
```

now, given that the `strLinqResult` is `IQueryable<string>`, I need to call it `strLinqResult.Bar<int,string>();`.

The point is **I have to pass both types, even though the first one is already known** as I'm calling the method on already defined `IQuerable`.

Since it was enough to call `Foo(2)` and **not** `Foo<string>(2)` I thought the compiler is able to "pass/guess" the type automatically.

So why do I need to call the second method `Bar<int,string>();` and not just `Bar<int>()` ?

---

the actual code:

```
    public static ListResponse<TResponse> 
        BuildListResponse<T,TResponse>(this IQueryable<T> iq, ListRequest request)
        where TResponse: new()
    {
        var result = iq.ApplyListRequestParams(request).ToList().ConvertAll(x => x.TranslateTo<TResponse>());
        var tcount = iq.Count();
        return new ListResponse<TResponse> {
                Items =  result,
                _TotalCount = tcount,
                _PageNumber = request._PageNumber ?? 1,
            };
    }
```

`ApplyListRequestParams` is kind of `Foo` method from the example code - it just applies pagination & ordering params available in `ListRequest` object.

`Items` is a `public List<T> Items` in a `class ListResponse<T>`.

`TranslateTo` is a method from ServiceStack.

The above method called on `IQueryable<T>` returned by NHibernate (T is Domain Model) takes the request parameters (ordering, pagination), applies them, and then transforms the results list from `DomainModel` to DTO Object of type `TResponse`. The list is then wrapped in a generic response class (generic, so it is reusable for many DTO types)

Comment: Have you tried switching the definition to `Bar<TSource, TTarget>(...)`?

Comment: @PinnyM yep, I did. it still says I need to pass 2 type parameters

Comment: @Jon I might have misunderstood the other solution, but extending the actual class is out of question - it needs to be the extension method!

Comment: @migajek: The linked answer suggests using a static method on a separate generic class (not the one you are working with). Alternatively you could arrange for the call to be made with extension method syntax using an intermediate type, but that would take *two* extension method calls. Using extension method syntax with just one call requires the compiler to infer just one of the type arguments, which it does not do.

Comment: @Jon thanks, so the simple and short answer is "it's impossible". Yet I don't find it the same question as mentioned by you, as the solution of the mentioned problem doesn't apply here.

Comment: @migajek: It applies 100%, only the syntax changes from `x.Foo<int>` to `NewClassCreatedForThisPurpose<int>.Foo(x)`. That's the best you can do.

Comment: @Jon the compiler says I can't define extension method on a generic class.

Comment: @Jon, sorry - now I see the difference. Thank you!

Comment: Suppose you added a `Bar<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)`.  If the compiler accepted your shorthand, then it would now be unambiguous whether `strLinqResult.Bar<string>();` referred to `Bar<string>` or `Bar<string, string>`.  I think this is what Johny Skovdal is getting at in his answer, but I wanted to spell it out.

Comment: Tim, thank you. I'm newbie at C# and generic programming, so this wasn't obvious to me.

Comment: You're welcome.  Of course my comment should say "it would now be ambiguous", not "unambiguous"... but you got what I meant. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, you're attempting to input as few parameters as possible. That's just not possible. It's all or none where it can figure all out on its own.

The problem with only specifying some, is that you will the be able to introduce a similar method with the 1 less type parameter, and will now have broken the implementation.

But any chance you could share your original problem as well? Might be able to let the compiler figure it out some other way?